# How to open WhatsApp from WKWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, whatsapp

I have an iOS app that contains a WebView that has a button that opens WhatsApp. The button is not working. What I should do to let WebView open WhatsApp?
If I open website in browser, it opens WhatsApp.

Comment: This is the error I see in Debugger output: 
[Process] 0x11c031e18 - [pageProxyID=18, webPageID=19, PID=9888] WebPageProxy::didFailProvisionalLoadForFrame: frameID=3, isMainFrame=1, domain=NSURLErrorDomain, code=-1002, isMainFrame=1

Comment: Ensure that the URL scheme for WhatsApp is correctly registered in the Info.plist file. The URL scheme for WhatsApp is `whatsapp://` and make sure the button in the WebView is correctly linked to the WhatsApp URL. The URL should be in the format `whatsapp://send?phone=<phone_number>&text=<message>`

Comment: the URL is whatsapp://send, but I get an unsupported URL error at 
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
                 didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!,
                 withError error: Error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution I found after research:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
                     decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction,
                     decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)
        {
            if let requestURL = navigationAction.request.url?.absoluteString,
            !requestURL.contains("https") && !requestURL.contains("http") {
                if requestURL == "whatsapp://send",
                   let urlString = requestURL.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed) {
                    if let whatsappURL = NSURL(string: urlString) {
                        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL as URL) {
                            UIApplication.shared.open(whatsappURL as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: { (Bool) in
                                
                            })
                        } else {
                            // Handle a problem
                        }
                    }
                }
                decisionHandler(.cancel)
            } else {
                decisionHandler(.allow)
            }
        }
```

Comment: No need to use `NSURL`. Stick with `URL`. You also need to mention that you have to list `whatsapp` in the list of "Queried URL Schemes" in Info.plist.

Comment: if found your solution why you didn't accept your answer? accept it and get that reputation.